# Sequelize not creating foreign keys on db as expected

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

[image: I have this]

Given this ERD, I'm trying to figure out why foreign keys are not being created on `documentChildren` and `documentAttribute` as they each have a column which should be a FK to `document`.

My sequelize models are all working fine, but i'm curious what i'm doing wrong in that real FK's are not being generated.

document migration:

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('documents', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
      },
      ...
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

documentChildren migration:

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('documentChildren', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
      },
      documentId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'documents',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      ...
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

documentAttribute migration:

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('documentAttributes', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
      },
      documentId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'documents',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      ...
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

document model associations:

```js
document.associate = function (models) {
    document.hasMany(models.documentAttribute)
    document.hasMany(models.documentChildren)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: it says `"documentId" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES documents(id)` . The references option is the FK - I think you're confused with indexes

Comment: Doh! You're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows

```
"documentId" uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES documents(id)
```

The `REFERENCES documents(id)` is the FK. Check [postgresql-docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-fk.html)

You are confused with the indexes creation, that does not mean having a FK.